# How to force 0^0 be 1 in Maxima?

Tags: maxima, exponentiation

It is suitable in many series and polynomials to treat 0^0 as 1.

Unfortunately, `Maxima` think it is `expt`.

How to force?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Use `tellsimp` to define a different rule for the simplification of `0^0`.

```
(%i1) display2d : false $
(%i2) simp : false $
(%i3) tellsimp (0^0, 1);
(%o3) [\^rule1,simpexpt]
(%i4) simp : true $
(%i5) 0^0;
(%o5) 1
(%i6) sum (k^k, k, 0, 5);
(%o6) 3414
```

Note that you must disable simplification (via `simp:false$`) before defining the rule, otherwise the default simplification (which triggers an error) is applied.